# parabola passes through $4$ points

Tags: conic-sections

> Finding maximum number of parabola which passes through the point $A(1,2)\;,\; B(2,1)\;\;,(3,4)\;\;,(4,3)$

what i try

from these $4$ point one can imagine that parabola symmetrical about $y=x$ line

so axis of parabola along the line $y=x$ and directrix along the line $x+y+c=0$, where $c$ is any constant

did not understand how do i solve further

help me to solve it please

Comment: "*From these 4 point one can imagine that parabola symmetrical about y=x line*"  What?  Why?  No.  There is not enough information immediately to assume that.

Comment: If you know nothing about the parabola, you can assume that the equation is $$ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$$ where $b^2-4ac=0$ is one of the determining equations.  Knowing four points on the parabola would be enough to find $(a,b,c,d,e,f)$ up to multiple.

Comment: I just realized that you don't have a non-degenerate parabola here.  The only "parabolic equations" that pass through your points are $(x-y-1)(x-y+1)=0$ and $(x+y-3)(x+y-7)=0$.  Each of these two equations just give you a union of two parallel lines.

Comment: The points are vertices of a rectangle.  You can't inscribe a rectangle in a (nondegenerate) parabola.

Comment: It can be shown that for four distinct points $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ on a plane, there exists a non-degenerate parabola passing through these four points if and only if they form a non-degenerate convex quadrilateral which is not a parallelogram.

Comment: And, if the quadrilateral has no pair of parallel sides, there will be two nondegenerate parabolae.

Comment: sorry my friends i have edited by problem

Comment: @jacky: It is inappropriate to change the nature of a question after it has been answered, as it makes any answerers look like they've misinterpreted the problem. Instead, you should post a separate question. (They're free!) You could/should link back to this one to give background context. ("I mis-stated my problem in *the previous question*, but ...")

Comment: actually i have post yesterday and i have seen answer today.ok @blue thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

You rightly noticed that the four points are symmetrical around $y=x$.
So change the variables accordingly
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  \xi  = y - x \hfill \cr 
  \eta  = y + x \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Leftrightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  x = {{\eta  - \xi } \over 2} \hfill \cr 
  y = {{\eta  + \xi } \over 2} \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

The four points become
$$
\left( {1,3} \right),\left( { - 1,3} \right),\left( {1,7} \right),\left( { - 1,7} \right)
$$

The parabola's axis is the $\eta$ axis, so its formula is
$$
\eta  - a = k\xi ^{\,2} 
$$

In any case it is clear that, since the points form a rectangle, there cannot be a single parabola passing through all of them.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

A parabola is of the form $y = ax^2 + bx + c$

We are told that it passes through the points $(1,2),(2,1)$ and $(3,4)$.  (*I suggest ignoring $(4,3)$ for now and revisit it later*)

That means that plugging in those $x$ and $y$ values, the fact that it passes through $(\color{blue}{1},\color{red}{2})$ implies that $\color{red}{2} = a\cdot \color{blue}{1}^2 + b\cdot \color{blue}{1} + c$.  Similarly we can find the equations that are implied by the parabola passing through the other points.

We have then this system of equations:

$$\begin{cases}2 = a + b + c\\1 = 4a + 2b + c\\ 4 = 9a + 3b + c\\\end{cases}$$

Now... this is a system of three linear equations and three unknowns which can by solved by standard means.

(*Now, consider including $(4,3)$ as well.  Does this affect the answer?*)

Comment: why we will take $y=ax^2+bx+c$ and why we can,take $x=ay^2+by+c$ and How can one assume that paroabola is symmetrical parallel to $x$ axis or parabola is symmetrical parallel to $y$ axis.

Comment: Wait ... Your comment to the question noted that there's not enough information to assume symmetry about $y=x$, yet you start your answer here by asserting that "a parabola is of the form [that assumes symmetry about a vertical line]". What's up with that?

Comment: @Blue that is a fair point.  In my experience it is most common to refer to functions of $x$ in problems like these.  My answer does make an assumption, one that I was not even aware of at the time, that by "parabola" we were explicitly referring to parabolic functions of $x$ which are indeed always of the form described.  For conics in general who aren't necessarily functions of $x$, then as commented above one could use the more general $ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$.

Comment: The big point though that I was trying to make was that one can convert the given information into a system of linear equations by plugging in the values of $x$ and $y$ into whatever standard form of whatever equation it is that you are interested in, be it quadratic functions of $x$, conics in general, or whatever other equation types as desired based on the specific contexts of the problem in question.

Comment: It will not be a system of linear equations.  Can't be when you get two solutions, which is in fact usually the case when solutions exist.

Comment: sorry my friends i have edited by problem