# How can a parabola pass through rectangular coordinates?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

One of the questions in my book asked me to find the equation of axis of parabola by giving the 4 points through which parabola passes.
The points were: $(1, 2), (2, 1),(3, 4), (4, 3)$. The solution provided explained that since line joining points $(1, 2), (2, 1)$ and  another line joining points $(3, 4), (4, 3)$ are parallel, so the line perpendicular to it would be the axis of parabola. But when I tried drawing it, how can a parabola pass through these 4 points since the length of both lines are equal?
Also, I had studied that locus of mid points of parallel chords of parabola is a straight line parallel  to the axis of parabola, but how can the solution say that **it would be the axis of parabola?**

Comment: As mentioned in [a comment here by Batominovski](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3559650/parabola-passes-through-4-points): 'I just realized that you don't have a non-degenerate parabola here. The only "parabolic equations" that pass through your points are $(x-y-1)(x-y+1)=0$ and $(x+y-3)(x+y-7)=0$. Each of these two equations just give you a union of two parallel lines.'